# Only with cron: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby, perl, cron

I have a perl script that uses system() to call a shell command, which uses ruby_executable_hooks.

When I run this script from the command line it executes flawlessly.

However when it runs from a cron job, I get one of two errors:
A) if I do not chdir() ie. working dir is /home/foobar

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

B) if I chdir( "[doc root]/cgi-bin" )

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:779:in `report_activate_error': Could not find RubyGem twurl (>= 0) (Gem::LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:214:in `activate'
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems.rb:1082:in `gem'
from /home/foobar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin/twurl:22
from /home/foobar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15
```

What might be the reason it cannot find certain files when run from cron?

Comment: Just after posting I noticed that /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8 is being reference whereas twurl is running under 1.9.3, and 1.9.3 is the default version. I don't know enough about ruby to know if this could be an issue or how to fix it.

Comment: Are you saying `$ENV{PATH}` includes the path to `ruby_executable_hooks`? Then it's probably a permission issue.

Comment: The `cron` execution environment is often not what one thinks it is.  What happens if you run a script that is merely `id; pwd; env | sort` both (a) interactively, and (b) under cron ?  Do you see a difference of significance?

Comment: Thank you Carl, ikegami and pilcrow. The output from the command line is too long to show here. I will shorten it and put it in a separate comment. Here is the output from the cron job: HOME=/home/username LANG=C LOGNAME=username MAILTO=cron@servername.com PATH=/usr/bin:/bin PWD=/home/username SHELL=/bin/bash SHLVL=1 USER=username _=/usr/bin/env

Comment: Here is a very truncated output from command line. I have removed irrelevant stuff and PATH, which is in next comment. CLASSPATH=.:/usr/local/jdk/lib/classes.zip GEM_HOME=/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551 GEM_PATH=/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551:/home/username/.rvm/gems/r‌​uby-1.9.3-p551@global IRBRC=/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551/.irbrc MY_RUBY_HOME=/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p551 RUBY_VERSION=ruby-1.9.3-p551 rvm_bin_path=/home/username/.rvm/bin rvm_path=/home/username/.rvm rvm_prefix=/home/username rvm_version=1.26.11 (latest)

Comment: Here is PATH from command line. PATH=/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/bin:/home/for‌​exdaily/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@global/bin:/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.‌​9.3-p551/bin:/home/username/perl5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/s‌​bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/username/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home‌​/username/.rvm/bin:/home/username/bin:/home/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3‌​-p551/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin

Comment: Is there any way to include the missing stuff either in the cron tab or permanently in the environment variables?

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables

Specifically, I just put ". $HOME/.profile;" in front of the cron command like so:

0 5 * * * . $HOME/.profile; /path/to/command/to/run

Thank you all for putting me on the right track.

Comment: OMG thank you so much! Almost 15 hours trying to solve and now it's fixed. thanks thanks and thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's almost certainly an issue with your environment variables. When running something from cron your `.bashrc` isn't activated, so environment variables that might set up, like which ruby version you are pointed to and what your `PATH` looks like are likely different.

How to fix this will depend on your environment and what tools, if any, you might be using to select your ruby version (rvm, chruby, rbenv, etc...).

You might want to use something like `which ruby` to figure out exactly what ruby to execute and use that in your crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why this works but if anyone is using RVM on MacOS this worked for me. I am running database backups using a gem called `backup`. I had to put the gem inside my app's Gemfile. Not sure why I have to cd to the app directory.

`* * * * * source /Users/john/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.7.1; cd /path/to/app && bundle exec backup perform -t mybackup`