# How can I run a rake task via cron?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rake, ruby-on-rails-5

I have and rails application and a rake task which I'm going to execute by cron around once in an hour. But the thing is that the task uses rails environment and some classes of my rails application. If I run it as ruby script, I'll have to include all the dependencies it uses and I think it's not possible to do it correctly and in a simple way. So I'll have to run  it as a rake task because it'll preserve all the dependencies, right? Then how can I run a rake task from cron?

Note that I prefer not to use any third-party solution when there's no necessity, in  this case I don't want to use the gem whenever or the like.

Comment: when you run it from the console, what do you type to make it work? You can put exactly that command-string into your crontab.

Comment: checkout whenever, simplifies life a lot :-) https://github.com/javan/whenever

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482131/only-with-cron-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 22):

You can add to your crontab something like

```
0 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /path/to/your/project && bundle exec rake foo:bar >> log/cron.log 2>&1'
```

This will run `foo:bar` task every hour and write `stdout` and `stderr` to `log/cron.log`.

Please notice `bundle exec` before `rake` command.
Using bundler ensure you that task will fetch correct environment.

To specify `RAILS_ENV` you can do

```
... && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake foo:bar
```

Answer (score 4):

Use whenever to simplify your life https://github.com/javan/whenever ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of a rake task:

```
task :foo => :environment do
  puts "Running rake task in environment: #{Rails.env}"
  # can access Models here or whatever
end
```

Note that the `=> :environment` part is optional, but it what makes your Rails environment to the task block.

You can put `rake run_my_task` in your cron job.

You may need to use something like `cd /home/$USER/my_rails app && rake run_my_task` to ensure that the cron runs the task from the Rails root directory.